# MySQL query for a list of all my (accepted) friends

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table like this:

```
| USER | FRIEND |
-----------------
|    1 |      2 |
|    2 |      1 |
|    1 |     16 |
|   16 |      1 |
|    1 |      4 |
```

I need to write a MySQL query to list all (accepted) friends of `user 1`, in this case, it should return `2` and `16`, but not `4`, as that friendship isn't accepted.

Is there any 1-query way to do this?

Comment: It's not possible if your table only consists of that. Either have another field to state "acceptance" or you need another table to join this with.

Comment: @mavili: you're wrong. This table contains everything it should and nothing more.

Comment: tell me how you can distinguish "accepted" friends from "not accepted" only looking at this table.

Comment: Both `1-2` and `2-1` exist. @mavili

Comment: I think I know how. is it when the other user also has the first user in their friends list?

Comment: @RiMMER the values are static to say ? or are you looking for a dynamic query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to write a MySQL query to list all (accepted) friends of user 1

Assuming that an *accepted fried* is a friend that has a two entries in the table, one from the user to the friend and another from the friend to the user(as you explained with the sample data in your question), then you can do this:

```
SELECT ID
FROM
(
      SELECT user AS ID FROM friends WHERE friend = 1
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT friend     FROM friends WHERE user = 1
) t 
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(ID) > 1;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2b95f/1)

This will give you:

```
| ID |
------
|  2 |
| 16 |
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this please:

```
select * from table1 a
join table1 b
on a.user = b.friend
and b.user = a.friend
;
```

[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b0def/12)

```
| USER | FRIEND |
-----------------
|    2 |      1 |
|    1 |      2 |
|   16 |      1 |
|    1 |     16 |
```

You may simplify to get the friends or user by changing the query and giving the exact user you need:

```
select A.FRIEND from table1 a
join table1 b
on a.user = b.friend
and b.user = a.friend
WHERE A.USER = 1
;

| FRIEND |
----------
|      2 |
|     16 |
```

Comment: Mahamoud thanks mate :) Yup it's possible to filter by either way, I just wanted to give the generic method first.